# Is it possible to configure log4net to make notification on error?

Tags: log4net

*I rephrased the question to avoid focusing on C# exception as an exception.*

By design log4net is silent utility, or as FAQ describes it as fail-stop system.

However such behaviour is opposite to what I need. And I need this:

- incorrect configuration -- notification event
- database provider missing -- notification event
- cannot log into database -- notification event

and so on and on.

So is it possible (and if yes, how?) to configure log4net to make a notification on error instead of silently ignoring it?

Comment: Hah, found it. It won't be done soon, see dates: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/LOG4NET-1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you talking about log4net internal debugging?

You can enable this as described here: http://logging.apache.org/log4net/release/faq.html#trouble-file-perm.

This will make sure that inernal log4net exceptions are logged too.

**EDIT** Can log4net throw exceptions at run time?
*No. log4net is not reliable. It is a best-effort and fail-stop logging system. By fail-stop, we mean that log4net will not throw unexpected exceptions at run-time potentially causing your application to crash.* See http://logging.apache.org/log4net/release/faq.html.

Comment: Thank you, but no. It is a way of showing all messages, errors, and so on, kind of trace. So for example in case of normal run you will get the trace as well. And I would like to get some event/exception on log failure. For example I call `log.Fatal("hello")` and because connection to DB is lost it cannot be logged. Thus I would like to get some event/exception in **such** case.

Comment: It does not have to be exception pe se. Event would be enough. Anyway, some way to notify me (i.e. my program) that logging failed.

Comment: In fact, it's kind of logical that logging does not raise exceptions or events. It has nothing to do with your application flow, so it should not interfere so that you can focus on the real business logic. But maybe you have a specific use case that requires this?

Comment: Why not? Event does not disturb your workflow. Either you hook to it, or not. It is completely seamless, and the benefit it you would be aware that something is going wrong.

Comment: Anyway, log4net does not support that it seems.

Comment: Another thought: as it is open source, you can always propose such feature or even write it yourself :)