# Can log4net be made "reliable" externally to surface exceptions?

Tags: c#, log4net

I have a C# application currently using log4net where a new requirement demands user activity **must** be logged and if logging does not occur the application must stop. Out of the box, log4net is "not-reliable" and will not surface run-time exceptions. Can this be overridden without changing the source code?

[According to the documentation](http://logging.apache.org/log4net/release/faq.html) ([and this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16172224/is-it-possible-to-configure-log4net-to-make-notification-on-error)), log4net will not and should not surface exceptions:

> No. log4net is not reliable. It is a best-effort and fail-stop logging
>   system.
>
> By fail-stop, we mean that log4net will not throw unexpected
>   exceptions at run-time potentially causing your application to crash.
>   If for any reason, log4net throws an uncaught exception (except for
>   ArgumentException and ArgumentNullException which may be thrown),
>   please send an email to the log4net-user@logging.apache.org mailing
>   list. Uncaught exceptions are handled as serious bugs requiring
>   immediate attention.
>
> Moreover, log4net will not revert to System.Console.Out or
>   System.Console.Error when its designated output stream is not opened,
>   is not writable or becomes full. This avoids corrupting an otherwise
>   working program by flooding the user's terminal because logging fails.
>   However, log4net will output a single message to System.Console.Error
>   and System.Diagnostics.Trace indicating that logging can not be
>   performed.

Can log4net be configured or wrapped to guarantee that if an exception occurs it will surface at run-time?

Comment: One option is to download the source and make a custom build that doesn't swallow exceptions and just throws them.  A bit of a hassle, but would work if other options don't. -> https://logging.apache.org/log4net/source-repository.html

Comment: Be careful with requirements like, `user activity must be logged`.  This is probably not _logging_ but user _auditing_.  IMO, auditing should be handled explicitly in the app, because there are often different consistency requirements.

Comment: +1 Davin, You are correct. The goal is auditing, not logging. (Rookie mistake) Since posting this question I set up XML serialization messages being sent out for use on Splunk containing the variables I want to audit: username, datetime, etc... If the message is not sent, an exception is thrown halting user activity. Problem solved!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No you can't, log4net guarantee that a log message is written. So user activity logging as in your requirement can't be logged by log4net. When you are thinking of changing the log4net source code to remove this, don't start. There a so many places where an exception can disappear, that making a new log system is far more reliable. Just write the logmessages directly where you want them, and because of your requirement you will never use the features log4net gives you in filtering/different appenders/ log levels/ etc.